# Sections scroll with different scrolling speed with Skrollr.js

Tags: javascript, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3, skrollr

I am working on my portfolio, and I could use some help from the community. Excepting the stated problem and some further refinements to finish the mobile version, everything works fine, and I would like to end this work quickly.

Here is the issue. On the desktop version, landing page sections are using a different scrolling speed, which create a poor graphical appearance during the scrolling. Each of these sections are structured in regards to the Bootstrap framework. I really don't know where to look for that, as I think having followed the required structure for implementing Skrollr.js . Could you help me on debbuging that ?

The website is http://pierreedouard.com , visiting this URL should be more practical than pasting the entire HTML+CSS here I guess ...

Thanks in advance, Pierre

Comment: Every smooth scroll is different some work but most of them do not work that well especially when you cross browser and os check you see many differences in behaviour. That is why I do not recommend it. Although I personally like the touch/feel it gives the website. I have tried out many smooth scrolling scripts and only one really stand out from the others when speaking terms of being smooth whith especially paralex effects fixed bg and all those kind of graphicall elements, also light weight/small in size. I forgot the name of it... I will come back tomorrow and let you know (if interested).

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if you give me the name

Comment: Here is the one I use: https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll-for-websites @pierre

Comment: @RensTillmann Thanks ! But I managed to solve the issue. It was only a matter of HTML/CSS structure (padding and margin to set only on the "deeper" elements)